# How to push authorized APIs scope into Google ManageOath through APIs using admin creds

Tags: google-api, google-apps

In Google Developer, I have created one Service Account OAuth2.0 project. To access certain APIs using Service Account, I need to manually push authorized APIs into ManageOauthClients (https://admin.google.com//AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients).

Lets say I want to push these scopes through some APIs.

Considering I have Admin user credentials or valid AccessToken/RefreshToken generated from web oauth2.0 for some set of APIs,
Is there a way I can push some other authorized APIs scope for my service account client id into ManageOauthClients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no programmatic way for a Google Apps admin to authorize a Service Account Client ID. You have two options:

1. Give the admin instructions on how to login to the admin console and add the Client ID and scopes.
2. [Publish your app on the Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing). Published apps offer a workflow through which admins can install your app and authorize your Service account to access the scopes.